# SQL QUERY: How to assign random different value of column in a table, to differents row in another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm developing a desktop application that works like Risiko!'s game, based on some database procedures.

I need to assign to each player a tot of rows which are not equal to each other assigned to other players.

I've tried for something like this, but doesn't work:

```
 `create or replace PROCEDURE  "giveterritory"
    (idpartita NUMBER,nr_partecipanti number )
   is

 begin

 DECLARE

 CURSOR cur_file IS

SELECT *
FROM Player
WHERE idgame = Player.idgame ;

var_cur cur_file%ROWTYPE;

cont number ;
nr_territories_gioc_prec number ;
G1_Terr int ;  
G2_Terr int ;  
G3_Terr int ;
G1_ID number;
G2_ID number;
G3_ID number;
begin

cont:=0 ;

for var_cur in cur_file 

loop

cont := cont + 1 ;  

    update territory
    set    Player_owner = var_cur.id_Player
    where ROWNUM = MOD( MOD ( number_RANDOM(),42 ) ,ROWNUM );
 G1_Terr := var_cur.number_territories_tot ;   -- mi salvo i territories del primo Player
 G1_ID := var_cur.id_Player ;
 end if ;
   if (cont=2 ) then 


    update territory
    set    Player_owner = var_cur.id_Player
    where ROWNUM = MOD( MOD ( number_RANDOM(),42 -G1_Terr ) , ROWNUM ) and id_territory NOT IN ( select Player_owner from territory where ;

    G2_Terr := var_cur.number_territories_tot  ;    
    end if ;
 if (cont=3 ) then 


    update territory
    set    Player_owner = var_cur.id_Player
    where ROWNUM <= 42 - G1_Terr - G2_Terr;
    --where ROWNUM <= 42 - var_cur.number_territories_tot * 2 ;
 G3_Terr := var_cur.number_territories_tot  ;   
 end if ;
 end loop;
 end;

end;`
```

number_random code:

```
        create or replace FUNCTION  "NUMBER_RANDOM"
      return NUMBER
      is
      numbrndm int;
      begin

         select dbms_random.value(1,99999999) into numbrndm
        from dual;
   return numbrndm;
   end;
```

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to randomize things but posting your structure and some sample data would be helpful.  Then the other question is do you really want random or more of a round robin so that your territories are balanced?

Comment: Balanced and randomized

Comment: Don't put SOLVED into the title. Accept the answer that solved your problem. If you solved it on your own, add the solution as an answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to assign each player a random set of territories?

If so, sort the territories in random order and assign them to players round robin.  Here's a `MERGE` statement that should do that.  I apologize for any minor syntax errors: I am not in front of an Oracle database right now.

```
MERGE INTO territory t
USING (
WITH players AS ( SELECT rownum player#, id_player
                  FROM   player
                  WHERE  idgame=:idgame ),
players_count AS ( SELECT count(*) players_count FROM players )
-- Get the id_player for each assignment
SELECT assignedt.id_territory, p.id_player
FROM
(
  -- Assign the randomly-ordered territories to players in round-robin format
  SELECT randt.id_territory, 
     mod(rownum, pc.players_count)+1 player#
  FROM (
    -- Query the territories in a random order
    SELECT t.id_territory
    FROM   territory t
    ORDER BY dbms_random.random ) randt, players_count pc
  -- Optional:
  -- ... add a where clause to limit rownum <= some number to make 
  -- ... sure each player receives an even number of territories. 
  -- ... You'd need the count of territories to do that.
  ) assignedt inner join players p on p.player# = assignedt.player#
) u
ON ( u.id_territory = t.id_territory )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.id_player = u.id_player;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put a random number column in your SQL selects for each row. Then you can order your record set by the random number directly in SQL.

Do this for both players and territory lists.

This example should work for any number of territories and players. If the territories don't divide up equally, it will be at random which players get one extra territory.

We are going to loop through the territories list once, in random order. We are going to step through the player list until we reach the end, then reload the player list again. This happens as many times as needed.

Might need to fix this for syntax or logic. I don't have an Oracle instance to test it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE giveterritory (pID_GAME PLS_INTEGER) IS
    CURSOR c_player IS
        SELECT id_player, dbms_random.value() rnd
        FROM players
        WHERE id_game = pID_GAME
        ORDER BY 2 desc;
    --
    CURSOR c_territory IS
        SELECT id_territory, dbms_random.value() rnd
        FROM territories
        WHERE id_game = pID_GAME
        FOR UPDATE of id_player
        ORDER BY 2 desc;
    --
    l_player_row  c_player%ROWTYPE;
    l_territory_row  c_territory%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_player;
    FETCH c_player into l_player_row;
    --
    FOR r in c_territory
    LOOP
        UPDATE territories
        SET id_player = l_player_row.id_player
        WHERE CURRENT OF c_territory;
        --
        FETCH c_player INTO l_player_row;
        IF c_player%NOTFOUND THEN
            CLOSE c_player;
            OPEN c_player;
            FETCH c_player INTO l_player_row;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it assigns every territories to last player, also the territories that don't belong to current game